# Stream of two Set flatMap to integers

Tags: java, java-stream

```
final Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
final Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();

Stream.of(set1, set2).mapToInt(???).forEach(intValue -> code)
```

I have 2 Set of Integer and in a Stream but i want to map them all into Integers. I can't find a way to do it using maptoInt or flatMap so i can extract all Integers of both Sets.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream())` which creates a new combined stream so you can then map  your values to int

Comment: You're the best. Thanks ! i was wasting my time with Stream.of

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors Since you are new to the site you may not be aware of "accepting an answer" mechanism. In short, when some answer solves problem from the question you can (although there is no obligation) mark it as solution by using ✔ (tick symbol) on the left side of that answer. More info at: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from stream concatenation mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675352 you can also use

```
Stream.of(set1, set2)
      .flatMap(set -> set.stream())  
      .mapToInt(i -> i)               
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

since `flatMap` expects mapping to Stream of *values* which should be "used" by current stream.

So in your case you want stream containing values inside each set which can be created via

- `set -> set.stream()`
- or `Set::stream`.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be even more elegant to use [`flatMapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function))?

Comment: @OleV.V. It would require mapping to `IntStream`, so we would end up with something like `.flatMapToInt(set -> set.stream().mapToInt(i->i))`. I don't know if it is more elegant/readable than `flatMap(..).mapToInt(..)`.

Comment: No, you’re right, your version is more straightforward to understand. Thanks for showing the difference. PS Anyone fond of method references may use `.flatMap(Set::stream)` and/or `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`.